# React useState hook causes infinite rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I'm listing all products according to the search query. I store all brands and sellers information of listed products in useState hook. Which until this point it works. Now I want to store all categories in useState hook.

> listProducts are the listed version of results. Thoose results can be sorted or filtered seperately by user. And defaultProducts will not be effected. defaultProducts is what I get from the database.

```
  const { query } = useParams();
  const [products, setProducts] = useState([]);
  const [listProducts, setListProducts] = useState([]);
  const [brands, setBrands] = useState([]);
  const [sellers, SetSellers] = useState([]);
  const [Categories, setCategories] = useState([]);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    
    axios
      .get(`/api/product/search/${query}`)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .then((data) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setProducts(data.products);
        setListProducts(data.products);

        if (data.products.length < 1) {
          setProducts(data.brands);
          setListProducts(data.brands);
        }
      });
  }, [query]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let brandSet = new Set();
    let sellerSet = new Set();
    let categoriesSet = new Set();

    products.forEach((item) => {
      categoriesSet.add(item.category);
      categoriesSet.add(item.subCategory);
      brandSet.add(item.brand);
      sellerSet.add(item.shop.companyName);
    });

    setCategories([...categoriesSet]);
    setBrands([...brandSet]);
    SetSellers([...sellerSet]);
  }, [products]);
```

And I finally render `ProductFilters` component.

```
 <ProductFilters
   DefaultProducts={products}
   ListProducts={listProducts}
   Brands={brands}
   Sellers={sellers}
   Categories={Categories}
   setListProducts={setListProducts}
   Brand={brand}
 />
```

In `ProductFilters.js`

```
<FilterTypeSection className="mt-3">
        <FilterType>Categories</FilterType>
        <CategoriesSection>
          {Categories.map((categoryItem, index) => {
            return (
              <CategoryItem
                key={index}
                onClick={
                  category === categoryItem
                    ? setCategory("")
                    : setCategory(categoryItem)
                }
                style={
                  categoryItem === category
                    ? { fontWeight: "bold", color: "black" }
                    : { fontWeight: "normal", color: "var(--text-muted)" }
                }
              >
                {categoryItem}
              </CategoryItem>
            );
          })}
        </CategoriesSection>
</FilterTypeSection>
```

I listed sellers and brands data like above and they worked. But when I added this code I got this error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/pages/searchResultsPage.js:162
  159 |   sellerSet.add(item.shop.companyName);
  160 | });
  161 | 
> 162 | setCategories([...categoriesSet]);
      | ^  163 | setBrands([...brandSet]);
  164 | SetSellers([...sellerSet]);
  165 |
```

Even if I set a default value for `Categories` prop like `Categories=["a","b","c"]` I still get same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Issue**

In your onClick function you are doing a function call `setCategory("")` . But what you need is a just a function signature which can be called at a later time when the user clicks it .

so change your onClick as an inline function.

```
onClick={() => {
  category === categoryItem
  ? setCategory("")
  : setCategory(categoryItem)
}
```

Comment: It worked thanks. But I just looked at react components section from google dev tools and I see this: Maximum update depth exceeded. Getting this error because of fetching data and setting brands, sellers and categories to different hooks. But website works.

Comment: Instead of doing sending request to server inside a hook should I do this in redux?

Comment: @GuneyRal How often does "query" change? Fetching data in a hook is not a problem, but of course, if you have a dependency that changes often (in this case query) this will trigger a lot of requests to the server.

Comment: @MartinZ "query" is a route parameter. I don't know if it changes frequently.

Answer (score 1):

The `setCategory` function will be called again and again if you don't use arrow function there. Your `ProductFilters` component should be like this:

```
<FilterTypeSection className="mt-3">
    <FilterType>Categories</FilterType>
    <CategoriesSection>
        {Categories.map((categoryItem, index) => {
            return (
              <CategoryItem
                key={index}
                onClick={
                  () => category === categoryItem
                    ? setCategory("")
                    : setCategory(categoryItem)
                }
                style={
                  categoryItem === category
                    ? { fontWeight: "bold", color: "black" }
                    : { fontWeight: "normal", color: "var(--text-muted)" }
                }
              >
                {categoryItem}
              </CategoryItem>
            );
        })}
    </CategoriesSection>
</FilterTypeSection>
```

Comment: It worked thanks. But I just looked at react components section from google dev tools and I see this: Maximum update depth exceeded. Getting this error because of fetching data and setting brands, sellers and categories to different hooks. But website works. Instead of doing sending request to server inside a hook should I do this in redux?